# Remove ComboBox values

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, workspace

TO the point:

I got one combobox with 10 values. 
When I use this line of code it deletes ALL of the items in my combobox.

```
cboTrainer.getItems().removeAll(cboTrainer.getItems());
```

The items are gone but **the white spaces are still there !**

I tried:

```
 cboTrainer.setVisibleRowCount(cboTrainer.getVisibleRowCount()-1);
```

Image of issue:

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a MVCE, since there was no empty rows in default usage of combobox. Also the JavaFX version you have.

Comment: What's MVCE ? i'm using NETBEANS IDE 8.0.2 and javafx 8.0.45-b11

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It may happen because of you are manipulating the list you are traversing. Anyway the right way of clearing the items would be:

```
cboTrainer.getItems().clear():
```

Comment: Still getting the white spaces

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
cboTrainer.getItems().remove();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.